# Counterexample to basis of subspace (Axler 2.B.7)

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stuck at a problem from the Axler (Linear algebra done right) 2.B.7

Prove or give a counterexample: If $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ is a basis of $V$ and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $v1,v2 \in U$ and $v_3 \notin U$ and $v_4 \notin U$, then $v_1,v_2$ is a basis of $U$.

While I looked up the solution and fully agree with it, I don't know a structured way how to come up with such a solution.

The solution (counterexample) provided:
let $V = \mathbb{R}^4, v_1 = (1,0,0,0), v_2=(0,1,0,0), v_3=(0,0,1,1),v_4=(0,0,0,1)$ and $U =\{(x,y,z,0)|x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}\}.$

Is it correct that for a counter example, I need to find $v_3,v_4$ such that one "contains" the other (like $(0,0,2,1),(0,0,2,0)$ or $(0,0,3,2),(0,0,3,1)$) and then let $U$ to be $\{(x,y,0,z)|x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}\}$ if $v_3-v_4 = \lambda(0,0,0,1)$ or $\{(x,y,z,0)|x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}\}$ if $v_3-v_4 = \lambda(0,0,1,0)$ (for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$).

Is there a more structured / more flexible way of solving this problem?

Comment: May be for intuition it's better to take $V=\mathbb R^2=Span\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and $U=Span\{(1,1)\}$. Neither $(1,0)$ nor $(0,1)$ belong to $U$, but $U\neq \{0\}$. I let you adapt this example to your exercise.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a very structured way to approach something like this - but one thing that helps me in problems like this is to try to prove the thing and see what happens. When you run into problems with a proof, you can see what's going wrong with the proof and see if that points you towards a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Prove or give a counterexample: If $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ is a basis of $V$ and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $v_1,v_2 \in U$ and $v_3 \notin U$ and $v_4 \notin U$, then $v_1,v_2$ is a basis of $U$.

Since $v_1, v_2$ are linearly independent we can say that $U$ will be *at least* 2-dimensional. But $v_1,v_2$ will be a basis for $U$ if and only if $U$ is *exactly* 2-dimensional. So the question is can we find subspace $U$ of dimension greater than two that which contains $v_1,v_2$ but does not contain $v_3$ and $v_4$. Note that if $U$ were 4-dimensional then $U$ would be all of $V$ so that wouldn't work. So we are specifically looking for a 3-dimensional.

Another way of phrasing it is that we are looking to extend the span of $v_1, v_2$ into a 3-dimensional subspace that avoids including $v_3,v_4$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want an "intuition" to find the counterexample. Here's one idea:
Consider the 4 dimensional space R^4 and let v1,...,v3 represent the x, y , z and w axes.
Now if you take u1=v1, u2=v2, u3=(v3+v4)
( you can orthogonalize if you want but that's unnecessary)
and U=span(u1,u2,u3), then its clear v1,v2 is in U but not v3 or v4

Basically, we "cooked up" a subspace that contains x axis, y axis, and the vector "halfway " between z and w axes but neither z nor w ........

hope this works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).